# How to disable Excel's autoformatting completely?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge Excel-sheet, with a column that looks like this:

```
12345
123-45
012-34
00123
01234
```

And I need to remove all the dashes from that column. But if I select the column and do a find-replace, and replace all dashed with nothing, then Excel gets clever on me and notices that all those cells are numbers and removes the prefixed zeros, so it looks like this:

```
12345
12345
1234
123
1234
```

But I need ma zeros! And now I have to fight another battle, trying to place those zeros again (and I don't want that).

Can I somehow disable Excels auto-formatting of cells *entirely*, - so all cells will be treated as text, regardless of what happens, until I tell it differently?

I tried marking the cells, formatting them to text and then do the search-replace - but for some reason this doesn't help.

I have looked in Excel's settings, but found nothing in there. :-/

Comment: I reproduce your data in Excel-2010 with set cells data format as "Text" (Excel marks some cells with green left upper corner marks reporting that a number data is formatted as a sting). After S&R no leading zeroes were removed.

Comment: Do you want to disable it BEFORE or AFTER you put in you're data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution was to copy the entire sheet into **Google Sheets** and do it there (where it worked flawlessly).

I played around with it for a while and tried all the suggestions from in here. I was on a Mac, Office 365, Excel version 15.33. I also tried moving it to a Windows and doing it there, and it acted in exacly the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Before you enter any values in the column/cells, change the cell format to Text.

**Here's How:**

1. Select All Column/Row or Sheet
2. Select Format type as "Text" from the Formatting menu

[image]

**Sample Result:**

[image]

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I tried that - and it didn't help. I tried both marking the cells, right click and choose 'Format' and choose 'Text'. And I also tried doing how you showed, - but it still removes the prefixed zeros. :-(

Comment: It does work on my side (screenshot added to answer). The columns must not be properly setting to "Text Format" so please try on blank sheet or new workbook.

Comment: @Zeth You must set data format to "Text" strongly after assigning the value. If you change the cell's value "by hands", you must re-set the cell format.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with, setting it strongly. I mark the column, choose 'Format' and choose 'Text'. Can I do it differently? 
And I just tried formatting it after the replacement, to see if that changed anything, - but it didn't. ... I can see that it works on yours, though. Hmm...

Comment: @Zeth [Try these](https://superuser.com/questions/39185/how-do-i-force-a-column-in-excel-to-be-stored-as-text) OR [these](https://professor-excel.com/force-cell-format-excel/) instructions to force field format as Text.

Answer (score 0):

*If you need to remove all the dashes from that column, write the following formula & fill it down:*

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-","")
```

**Edited:** *Since you want leading zeros to be remained after Hyphen been removed in that case you need to use the following formula.*

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""),"00000")
```

[image]

**Note:**

*I'm assuming that the column A has been Custom Formatted with `00000` to accommodate leading zeros in the cells.*

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But I'm afraid you're showing me a mixed result. The zero remains on line 3, but are removed on line 4 and 5. And I want the zeroes to remain. I want only the dashes gone, - and everything else left as it is.

Comment: @Zeth, now check the edited formula which keeps the leading zeros also, as you have written in comments.